# How to make rotation on its own object space?

Tags: android, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

I am drawing a cube.And I want it to rotate in the object space. The code below makes the cube move around some axis other than its own. So any suggestions thanks in advance.

```
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config){
    // Set the background frame color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.2f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    cube = new Cube();     
}           

//  @Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height){
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);        
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    float angle, near, far, bottom, top,left, right;
    angle = 45.0f;
    near = 1.0f;
    far = 10.0f;

    top = near * (float)Math.tan(angle*(Math.PI/360.0));
    bottom = -top;
    left = bottom * ratio;
    right = top * ratio;

    Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}

//@Override 
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {        
    // Draw background color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    Matrix.setRotateM(rotationXMatrix, 0, mAngleX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.setRotateM(rotationYMatrix, 0, mAngleY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(rotationMatrix, 0, rotationXMatrix, 0, rotationYMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, rotationMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(ModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);

    cube.draw(ModelViewProjectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm:

1. Get current model position (x,y,z) from ModelMatrix * playerCentre
2. Set ModelMatrix to IdentityMatrix
3. Translate object to 0,0,0
4. Rotate wrt z-axis to 0
5. Translate along y-axis by ds
6. Rotate to total rotation of zAngle
7. Set ModelMatrix using steps 3,4,5,6
8. Repeat step 1
9. Repeat step 2
10. Translate object to 0,0,0
11. Rotate wrt z-axis to zAngle
12. Translate object to model position in step 1 + model position in step 8

Code:

```
private static void updateModel(int upDown, float xAngle, float yAngle, float zAngle) {
    Matrix.setIdentityM(GLES20Renderer._RMatrix, 0);

    //Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer.RMatrix, 0, xAngle, 0, 1, 0);
    //Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer.RMatrix, 0, yAngle, 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(GLES20Renderer._RMatrix, 0, zAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    _ds = upDown - GLES20Renderer._upDown;

    float[] RMatrix         = new float[16];
    float[] TMatrix         = new float[16];
    float objX              = 0.0f;
    float objY              = 0.0f;
    float objZ              = 0.0f;
    float objTempTranslateX = 0.0f;
    float objTempTranslateY = 0.0f;
    float objTempTranslateZ = 0.0f;

    //////////////////////////////////////
    // transformations for nozzle start //
    //////////////////////////////////////
    Matrix.multiplyMV(GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre, 0);
    //collision parameter
    objX    = GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0];
    objY    = GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1];
    objZ    = GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[2];

    Log.d("ZAXIS", "OBJY: " + GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1]);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(TMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(TMatrix, 0, 0, (float)GLES20Renderer._ds/10, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, TMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._RMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentre, 0);

    objTempTranslateX   = GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[0];
    objTempTranslateY   = GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[1];
    objTempTranslateZ   = GLES20Renderer._uNozzleCentreMatrix[2];

    Matrix.setIdentityM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(TMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(RMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(TMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(RMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, RMatrix, 0, TMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._RMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(TMatrix, 0);
    if( Math.abs(GLES20Renderer._ds) > 0 ) {
        Matrix.translateM(TMatrix, 0, (objX + objTempTranslateX), (objY + objTempTranslateY), (objZ + objTempTranslateZ));          
    }
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, TMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._ViewMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._ProjectionMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixNozzle, 0);
    /////////////////////////////////////
    // transformations for nozzle end  //
    /////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////
    // transformations for body start //
    ////////////////////////////////////
    Matrix.multiplyMV(GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentreMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0, GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentre, 0);
    //collision parameter
    objX    = GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentreMatrix[0];
    objY    = GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentreMatrix[1];
    objZ    = GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentreMatrix[2];

    Matrix.setIdentityM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(TMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(RMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(TMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(RMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0, RMatrix, 0, TMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(TMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(TMatrix, 0, 0, (float)GLES20Renderer._ds/10, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0, TMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0, GLES20Renderer._RMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentreMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0, GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentre, 0);

    objTempTranslateX   = GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentreMatrix[0];
    objTempTranslateY   = GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentreMatrix[1];
    objTempTranslateZ   = GLES20Renderer._uBodyCentreMatrix[2];

    Matrix.setIdentityM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(TMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(RMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(TMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(RMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0, RMatrix, 0, TMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0, GLES20Renderer._RMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(TMatrix, 0);
    if( Math.abs(GLES20Renderer._ds) > 0 ) {
        Matrix.translateM(TMatrix, 0, (objX + objTempTranslateX), (objY + objTempTranslateY), (objZ + objTempTranslateZ));          
    }
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0, TMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixBody, 0, GLES20Renderer._ViewMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixBody, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixBody, 0, GLES20Renderer._ProjectionMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._MVPMatrixBody, 0);
    ///////////////////////////////////
    // transformations for body end  //
    ///////////////////////////////////

    GLES20Renderer._upDown  = upDown;
    //collision parameter
    Matrix.multiplyMV(GLES20Renderer._uPlayerCentreMatrix, 0, GLES20Renderer._ModelMatrixNozzle, 0, GLES20Renderer._uPlayerCentre, 0);
}
```

Here upDown is the current value of the number of times a clickable ui view (eg ui button) is pressed for moving the cube along where the head points, infact there are two buttons one for up and other for down, in the above code I have two cubes nozzle and body

**Please try to implement the algorithm by yourself because the code given has an error that causes auto increment in objY**

I have less time so code is not edited for your ready use, that is from my app.

I have posted the same question, but I am waiting for reply, the algorithm is absolutely correct only code has error.

Here is my question:
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817450/rotation-about-local-z-axis**